# MongoDB finding nested elements

Tags: json, mongodb, database

I am using the MongoDB shell and I need to find some nested elements.
My structure looks like this:

```
 car : { "$ref" : "cars" , "$id" : { "$oid" : "4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63"}}
```

I need to get to the `oid = 4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63`

thanks in advance

Here is the structure :

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4e7c6b68e4b0dea06288ad22"} , 
  "driver" : "Test Driver" , 
  "category" : "BUSINESS" , 
  "distanceM" : 216.857 , 
  "mileageKmStart" : 121813.943 , 
  "mileageKmEnd" : 122030.8 , 
  "timestampStart" : { "$date" : "2012-01-12T11:20:08Z"} , 
  "timestampEnd" : { "$date" : "2012-01-12T11:21:11Z"} , 
  "car" : { 
      "$ref" : "cars" , 
      "$id" : { "$oid" : "4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63"}
   }
}
```

Comment: check my updated answer, it should be used like `'car.$id.$oid'`

Comment: The key "$oid" is illegal - field names cannot start with $. Are you _sure_ that's your db structure? Mongo will normall store such data as ` "car" : { "$ref" : "cars" , "$id" : ObjectId("4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63")}}

Comment: @AD7six, thats right. Backlit you cannot use $ on field names. It throw error on insert. i wonder how could you possibly inserted the doc?

Comment: I didn't designed the structure. But I think its some kind of reference to an other collection. Would this be the reason I can't read or edit the data?

Comment: @AD7six, i found some weird behaviors with $ insertion. i have raised the seperate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984162/weird-behavior-with-mongo-db-fields-start-with have a look

Answer (score 4):

After a tiny dig around...

`mongoexport` will represent object ids as "$oid". Are you reading a json file generated by `mongoexport`? If so that is *not* the structure of your documents when imported (Or it is, but when you use a client to talk to mongo it does not want you to use this syntax).

Almost certainly, you want:

```
db.x.find({'car.$id': ObjectId('4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63')})
```

If that isn't the case - have a look in the mongo cli - e.g. run:

```
db.x.findOne()
```

or

```
db.x.findOne({'car' : {$exists: true}}) // make sure the one I find has a car
```

If you've managed to create/inherit data with illegal keys - you'll probably want to migrate their structure so that it is possible to query your data.

---

[DBRefs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef) are a convention for how to create references to different collections - Note specifically "convention". They aren't special (except they are permitted the keys $ref, $id and $db) in any way - they are just another javascript object to mongo.