# Weird behavior with mongodb fields start with $

Tags: exception, mongodb, special-characters

On this post [MongoDB finding nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983482/mongodb-finding-nested-elements), author claims that the mongodb document structure is

```
      car : { "$ref" : "cars" , "$id" : { "$oid" : "4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63"}}
```

When i tried to reproduce the problem, i encountered some weird behaviors with mongodb insertion

When  run the insertion on above sample data, i got following error

```
> db.sample.insert({car:{ "$ref" : "cars" , "$id" : { "$oid" : "4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63"}}})
Tue Jan 24 14:09:07 uncaught exception: field names cannot start with $ [$oid]
```

it says that field names cannot  start with `$`.

If thats the case, it should not work if i remove `$` from oid and left the remaining `$ref` & `$id` untouched

```
    > db.sample.insert({car:{ "$ref" : "cars" , "$id" : { "oid" : "4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63"}}})
    > db.sample.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f1e6fbc403aae757ec6dea5"), "car" : { "$ref" : "cars", "$id" : { "oid" : "4e8478ace4b0dea06288ad63" } } }
```

surprisingly it worked. Now it accepts the fields start with $

Also when i tried this query

```
> db.sample.insert({ "$ref" : "cars" })
document to insert can't have $ fields
```

i got the error back.

I don't understand what causes this? anybody have a clear idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$id` and `$ref` are special identifiers used for [dbrefs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References). Otherwise, field names starting with a `$` aren't allowed.

However, your first-level document must not be a dbref itself, hence the error "document to insert can't have $ fields".

However, dbrefs are allowed as subdocuments, e.g. (from the [official docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References))

```
"name" : "Joe",
"classes" : [
        {
                "$ref" : "courses",
                "$id" : ObjectId("4b0552b0f0da7d1eb6f126a1")
        }
]
```

Now `$oid` is not a special identifier, and is not allowed because the `$` has special semantics: Think of `$inc`. That is an operator, but if `$` field names were allowed, it could also be the name of a field.

You have to be careful when using the [positional operator in updates](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator):

> The positional operator cannot be combined with an upsert since it requires a matching array element. If your update results in an insert then the "$" will literally be used as the field name.

Comment: is there a way to chance the DBRefs?

Comment: @Backlit: I'm sorry I don't understand the question. You want to change the syntax of the dbrefs? Make sure you understand that you don't have to use dbrefs - in fact, it's usually not required and the official docs recommend you use a simple direct links, like `UserId: 423434`.

Comment: @mnemosyn: I didn't design the structure. (I'm the author of the initial problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983482/mongodb-finding-nested-elements)  And I can't chance the structure by just deleting the DBref and creating a direct link. The database is in use. Thats why I want to chance the dbrefs - if possible.

Comment: `$ref`, `$id` and `$db` are reserved keywords and cannot be changed. The dbrefs' name can be changed though.

Comment: I meant if it is possible to chance the reference value.

Comment: Changing the values is no problem: `db.example.update({ criteria }, {$set : { "myref.$ref" : "newValue" } });`

Answer (score 1):

`$ref` `$id` and `$db` are the only valid keys which begin with a dollar sign - they are related to the [DBRef](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References#DatabaseReferences-DBRef) convention.

The reason you can't use your own keys starting with a dollar sign is becuase it has [Special](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) [meaning](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations) and would otherwise create ambiguity.

Comment: Is there anyway around this?  For instance, escaping them?