# Mongo invalid document for insert: keys cannot begin with "$": "$date"

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a script that is moving some documents from one collection to another, so if a document met the needed criteria I'm inserting it into another collection and removing it from the original collection. And one document failed with the error `invalid document for insert: keys cannot begin with "$": "$date"` because it has an field like:

```
   "rerender_at" : {
        "$date" : {
            "$numberLong" : "1485872000000"
        }
    },
```

But if mongo does not allow to insert of fields with `$` how it's possible that the document has that data already??? Or if it's possible to insert, how can I do it???

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984162/weird-behavior-with-mongodb-fields-start-with) topic it's not allowed to insert

Comment: What client do you use? $date and $numberLong seem like representation of BSON done on the driver/client level

Comment: well, I do not know how it was inserted, we had 40+ million rows in that collection, which was added over years. The migration script is written in PHP, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/set.mongodb.php

Comment: BTW, other date fields stored like `ISODate` objects, and PHP working with it correctly

Comment: I did not ask how they were inserted, I ask what client do **you** use to get these documents from the database.

Comment: I'm using https://www.php.net/manual/ru/set.mongodb.php, also I can see the same structure when querying through Robo 3T

Comment: and this extension/driver https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "$date" : {
        "$numberLong" : "1485872000000"
}
```

is BSON date in canonical extended JSON format https://mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-Date

You cannot insert it directly but need to convert it to [MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php)

Comment: it means I need to convert it like `new UTCDateTime($data['$date']['$numberLong'])` ??? And can you explain to me please how it was inserted that way, I'm wondering if It'll not break some other parts of the app  if I change it to UTCDateTime

Comment: Without seeing the data I can only speculate it was a bug in a driver, backup/restore utilities, may be database upgrade.  The restriction is set on the driver level, not storage engine. It's mostly to distinguish between mongo query language operators and data, yet there are some exceptions, e.g. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/

Comment: I would recommend to read https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restrictions-on-Field-Names, compare with previous version https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restrictions-on-Field-Names As they put it "There is a small chance of data loss", so please test it, especially if you use clients in different languages .